# VB6 intellisense problems

Tags: syntax, vb6, radio-button, intellisense

I am writing a simple application that utilizes option(radio) buttons in vb6.
I am attempting to make different buttons and labels appear based on which optionbutton has  been selected. I attempted to use an if statement that looks like this:

```
If (EditOpenTicketRadioButton.value = True) Then
label.visible = true
elseIf(...) then....
and on.
```

things start acting strange when I begin to type the period after EditOpenTicketRadioButton. the only options that intellisense gives me are Count, Item, LBound, and UBound. I know from internet examples It should be like the above example right?  it will not run with that syntax it gives me an error that states: compile Error: Method or data member not found. then it points me to the Load method for my form...

If anyone can help me make sense of this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the (very, very) limited information you gave, I can only assume `EditOpenTicketRadioButton` is a victim of extremely poor name choice and is actually an *array* of radio buttons.

If that's the case, you need to figure out which button you mean, and use it like `EditOpenTicketRadioButton(0)` or whatever.

Comment: Or if it's index was set accidently (as you didn't think it was a control array) then just remove the index property.